SciPy `make_interp_spline` argument `bc_type` for 2D arrays
I'm trying to create a 2D parametric BSpline fit using make_interp_spline based off of some data that came from a NUBR spline, which includes two unit vectors denoting the tangents at either end of the curve. The issue I'm having is I'm not sure how the bc_type argument should be formatted when y is a 2D array.
I tried the following:
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
import numpy as np

def magnitude(x, y):
    return np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
xy = np.zeros(shape=(t.shape[0], 2))
xy[:,0] = 5*t
xy[:,1] = 2.5*t
tangent_start = (-0.9243451992527411, -0.38155727305138615)
tangent_end = (-0.8379592954605802, -0.5457327360083948)

# Passing in the tangent components
spline = make_interp_spline(t, xy, bc_type=([(1, tangent_start[0], 1, tangent_start[1])], [(1, tangent_end[0], 1, tangent_end[1])]))

However I get the error:
*** ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
I then tried just using the magnitudes:
spline = make_interp_spline(t, xy, bc_type=([(1, magnitude(tangent_start))], [(1, magnitude(tangent_end))])

However, I get the following error:

*** ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (2)

Is there a way to enter the bc_type data for a 2D array? make_interp_spline is able to fit to 2D data so somehow it's doing it when bc_type is left as None. Or do I have to fit separately to x(t) and y(t)?
